# Reffering / returning value's source cell address from ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(j) / VBA / Excel / PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I've got chart in Excel/PowerPoint. In this chart I would like to get value's source cell address for every data point from

`ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(y)`

Because Excel makes series automatically (this chart is made not with VBA) so I don't make this refference from scratch (not defining data series myself).
I know how to make it an opposite way - how to make SeriesCollection.Point from exact cells, but I would like to use this on ready-made charts, so don't want to define charts from scratch in VBA again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple solution for chart placed in activesheet in Excel. There are some assumptions and tips stated in comments in the code.

```
Sub GetSourceCellsAddress()

'define chart first...
Dim CH As Chart
Set CH = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

'...and its first series (which is line type)
Dim SC As Series
Set SC = CH.SeriesCollection(1)

'what we need is a series formula where you find reference to the range
Dim strFormula As String
    strFormula = SC.Formula
    'test here:
    Debug.Print strFormula  'result: =SERIES(Sheet1!$D$3,,Sheet1!$D$4:$D$8,1)

'but in fact we need the range with cell values, retrieve it from the formula
Dim strRangeFromFormula As String
    strRangeFromFormula = Mid(strFormula, _
                        InStrRev(strFormula, "!") + 1, _
                        InStrRev(strFormula, ",") - InStrRev(strFormula, "!") - 1)
    'test here
    Debug.Print strRangeFromFormula 'result: $D$4:$D$8

'in fact our point PT is a range type, so, iterate through cells
Dim rngPT As Range
For Each rngPT In Range(strRangeFromFormula)
    Debug.Print rngPT.Address   'results >>$D$4, $D$5, $D$6, $D$7, ....
Next rngPT

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank Kaz!
It works brilliant besides the last part:

'Dim rngPT As Range
For Each rngPT In Range(strRangeFromFormula)
    Debug.Print rngPT.Address
Next rngPT'

where I got error 'Compile error: User-deifned type not defined'

Comment: in which line exactly? as I said, this is for Excel, if you run it in PowerPoint you need some extra work.

Comment: an the answer to my last question is...??

Comment: It crushes on line: 'Dim rngPT As Range'

Comment: So then it crashes on `For Each rngPT In Range(strRangeFromFormula)`, with a message "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined". But accepts `Dim rngPT as Object`.

Comment: As I said, my solution works for Excel, you need to make some more adjustments to have it working in PowerPoint...

Comment: OK, thanks thanks a lot!
Maybe you've got any advices how to do this? And why this works in Excel, but not in PowerPoint?

Comment: It is a bit complicated by try to follow example in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff744350%28v=office.14%29.aspx)